# Cablerator vs Curve Basher

Tags: modeling, add-on

are there tools in the addon Cablerator 1.3 like the tools in the videos below?

[image]

this above making the cables align according to the clip created in them?

and the resource below
preferably the more complex cable which is the one below in the image

[image]

thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: That's a third-party paid-for addon. The official docs for it are [here](https://blendermarket.com/products/cbl).